# How to concate two dataframes which have different row items

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
df1
SR   NAME   ROLL
1    kk      123
2    mm      456
3    pp      789
4    hh      891

df2

ID    Marks
143     45
123     65
```

I want to combine such that output should look like

```
df3
SR   NAME   ROLL   Id     marks
1    kk      123   143    45
2    mm      456   123    65
```

The output rows should consist same as second dataframe
suppose in the above `df1` has 4 rows and `df2` has 2 rows
output `df3` should be only 2 (Note: I don't have any common columns in both)

Comment: Please take into notice, that your question doesn't really make sense, as you are combining two data sources without match and with different sizes, so there is no reason to think that the line 1 in `df2` is related to line 1 in `df1`, unless you have external information that it **must** refer to the same data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the two data frame and remove all rows which has any `NA`

```
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['kk','mm','pp','hh'],'ROLE':[123,456,789,891]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123,143],'MARKS':[45,65]})
df3 = pd.concat([dat1, dat2], axis=1).dropna(how='any')
df3

    NAME    ROLE    ID      MARKS
0   kk      123     123.0   45.0
1   mm      456     143.0   65.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=df1.index, right_on=df2.index).drop('key_0',axis=1)
```

Outouts:

```
   SR NAME  ROLL   ID  Marks
0   1   kk   123  143     45
1   2   mm   456  123     65
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).dropna()
```

The output will be:

```
SR   NAME   ROLL   Id     marks
1    kk      123   143    45
2    mm      456   123    65
```

Comment: May I ask what do the 3 middle lines do? Why not just `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` in the first place?

Comment: @Aryerez Sorry my bad i was using df1 as json so that's why i used middle lines to convert json to dataframe. I have updated